C++11 Динамическая инициализация и уничтожение с параллелизмом (магическая статика)
Изучаю С++ по документу:
https://ru.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support/11
В этой таблице (документ) есть пункт Динамическая инициализация и уничтожение с параллелизмом (магическая статика) по ссылкам:
https://ru.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration#.D0.A1.D1.82.D0.B0.D1.82.D0.B8.D1.87.D0.B5.D1.81.D0.BA.D0.B8.D0.B5_.D0.BB.D0.BE.D0.BA.D0.B0.D0.BB.D1.8C.D0.BD.D1.8B.D0.B5_.D0.BF.D0.B5.D1.80.D0.B5.D0.BC.D0.B5.D0.BD.D0.BD.D1.8B.D0.B5
https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2008/n2660.htm
в одной из ссылок идет описание thread_local - хотя описание thread_local дано в предыдущем пункте документа C++11 Локальная память потока.
У меня туговато пока с английским, можно простыми словами объяснить - о чем речь в изменении С++11 Динамическая инициализация и уничтожение с параллелизмом (магическая статика)?

Знаете, я бы посоветовал учить не чисто теоретически, а практически. Непонятно, как что-то работает? А какие есть идеи? Может, вот так надо понимать? Набрасываем тестовый пример, пробуем. Получилось? Нет, результат не такой, как ожидалось? А какой? Подумали, почитали еще раз. Опять простой тестовый пример... Кстати, если вы только читаете, но не закрепляете прочитанное хоть минимальной практикой — это чтение впустую.

Ну и я бы вообще не советовал учить язык, используя как учебник стандарт. Все равно что в младших классах, объясняя, как поступать не надо, прибегать к формулировкам из УК :) Что же до сути вопроса — то опять же непонятно, что именно вам непонятно. Просто перевести с английского весь документ? :) Было бы куда проще, если бы вы задавали конкретные вопросы, а не просили трактовать стандарт.

И еще... По-моему, лучше уж если учить стандарт — то сам стандарт, а не все эти предложения/обсуждения JTC... Все мои комментарии, естественно, являются моим личным мнением и не более того :) Сам Страуструп где-то писал, что не надо знать весь С++, чтобы писать хорошие программы. Так что я бы шел не от стандарта к задачам, а от задач к стандарту. Естественно, при беглом обзоре, а что вообще С++ умеет, чтобы при решении своих задач иметь представление, куда именно копнуть, если что понадобится — просто чтоб не открывать Америку через форточку...

Обсуждение посвящено следующему вопросу, на примере кода:
...
    if(c) {
        static T s;
        thread_local T t;
        ...
    }
...

Будут ли вызваны конструкторы, и если будут, то когда.
До C++11 thread_local вообще не было, а некоторые потенциально возможные реализации конструктора s, на "чистом" C++98, конфликтовали со сложившейся практикой использования C++ в рамках POSIX или Windows многопоточных программ.
А в C++11 этот вопрос изложен по-новому и более строго.
